# Does libmapi-2.0 exist?

Tags: evolution, evolution-mapi

After spending hours trying to compile evolution-mapi from source on 13.10, I've finally run into

```
checking for LIBMAPI... no
configure: error: libmapi wasn't found! Please install at least libmapi-2.0!
```

Though `libmapi-dev` is installed on my system, I've no evidence that `libmapi-2.0` even exists. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: `apt-cache search mapi` to search for available packages. If comes up with the silly error, it means it wont work without it.

Comment: yields what I expected - libmapi0 and a few related packages but not the required one.

Comment: The package name does not always match what it will install though. This does seem to be a rather weird problem. Are those packages listed installed?

Comment: yes, they're installed. doesn't satisfy the config requirements. still calls for libmapi-2.0.

Comment: Don't know then - is says `at least libmapi-2.0` though...

Answer (score 0):

libmapi is part of the openchange project from openchange.org.  You can get the required version from there.

It depends on Samba 4 to compile.  I'm not sure if that's available in Ubuntu or not.  You may end up compiling your way down the dependency tree.  :)  Checkinstall is your friend in that case.

Additionally, libmapi-2 appears to be available in Debian unstable.  You could try grabbing that directly and see if it's compatible with Ubuntu.  If it is not, then you could grab the source package and build that to get it.  I can't guarantee that will work, but it does about 90% of the time in my experience, although occasionally you end up having to do the same with some dependencies.  Backing up your system before you start is highly recommended.

Hopefully this works for you.  Sadly I can't give you exact steps since I'm not trying to do this on Ubuntu myself, but it should be what you need to know to figure it out from here.